# Data not saved into Firestore through scheduler function with Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, axios, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create APIs with Firebase Cloud Functions so as to build a system to make what's collected through the APIs and other third-party APIs routinely saved into Firestore. Here is my source code `index.js` at this moment, and I'd like to control all the processes in this one file.

`/functions/index.js`

```
const firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
const firebaseFunctions = require("firebase-functions");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();
const fireStore = firebaseAdmin.firestore();

const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");

const serviceToken = "SERVICE-TOKEN";
const serviceBaseUrl = "https://api.service.com/";

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const getAllExamples = async () => {
    var url = `${serviceBaseUrl}/examples?token=${serviceToken}`;
    var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        headers: {}
    };
    axios(config).then((res) => {
        console.log("Data saved!");
        return res.data;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Data not saved: ", err);
        return err;
    });
}

const setExample = async (documentId, dataObject) => {
    fireStore.collection("examples").doc(documentId).set(dataObject).then(() => {
        console.log("Document written!");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Document not written: ", err);
    });
}

app.get("/getAllExamples", (req, res) => {
    getAllExamples().then((response) => res.send(response));
});

app.put("/setExample", (req, res) => {
    setExample(req.params.documentId).then((response) => res.send(response));
});

const api = firebaseFunctions.https.onRequest(app);
module.exports = { api };

module.exports.updateExamplesRoutinely = firebaseFunctions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("America/Los_Angeles").onRun((context) => {
    var examples = getAllExamples();
    for(var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
        var example = examples[i];
        var exampleId = example["id"];
        if(exampleId && example) setExample(exampleId, example);
    }
});
```

As a result, `updateExamplesRoutinely` is properly triggered every 00:00 in PST, but NO data is stored in Firebase and NO console logs about Firebase data updates and found in Cloud Functions Logs.

Output data collected through `https://api.service.com/` is something like this below:

```
[
  {
    id: "BB345",
    name: "Tim Gordon",
    age: 24,
    email: "tgordon@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
    id: "CC098",
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 28,
    email: "john.doe@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: "DD777",
    name: "Adam Smith",
    age: 39,
    email: "adamsmith@outlook.com"
  },
  ...
]
```

Simply, these 3 problems are what I would like to get resolved.

1. How should I call APIs defined in `index.js` through Cloud Functions' scheduler?
2. How should I save data into Firestore inside Cloud Functions' scheduler?
3. What's the best "async" way to call the third-party APIs, wait and collect the results, and pass them to other events or functions?

Answer (score 1):

> How should I call APIs defined in index.js through Cloud Functions'
> scheduler?

I guess you want to say "How should I call **the methods** defined in index.js". There is no reason to call the APIs exposed by the Cloud Funtion from this same Cloud Function.

So to call the methods, do as follows:

```
const getAllExamples = async () => {
    var url = `${serviceBaseUrl}/examples?token=${serviceToken}`;
    var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: url,
        headers: {}
    };
    return axios(config).then((res) => {   // !!! note the return here
        console.log("Data saved!");
        return res.data;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Data not saved: ", err);
        return err;
    });
}

const setExample = async (documentId, dataObject) => {
    // !!! note the return on next line
    return fireStore.collection("examples").doc(documentId).set(dataObject).then(() => {
        console.log("Document written!");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Document not written: ", err);
    });
}

module.exports.updateExamplesRoutinely = firebaseFunctions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("America/Los_Angeles").onRun(async (context) => {
    const examples = await getAllExamples();

    const promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
        var example = examples[i];
        var exampleId = example["id"];
        if(exampleId && example) promises.push(setExample(exampleId, example));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
    // See how we return the promise returned by Promise.all
    // !!! This is IMPORTANT, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions 

});
```

> How should I save data into Firestore inside Cloud Functions'
> scheduler?

The above code will save the data in Firestore. You actually want to execute a variable number of call to the `setExample()` method, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as shown above. This way, `setExample()` will write to Firestore for each `example`.

> What's the best "async" way to call the third-party APIs, wait and
> collect the results, and pass them to other events or functions?

See how we adapt the `updateExamplesRoutinely` Cloud Function: we use the `async` and `await` keywords.

```
module.exports.updateExamplesRoutinely = firebaseFunctions.pubsub.schedule("0 0 * * *").timeZone("America/Los_Angeles").onRun(async (context) => {
    const examples = await getAllExamples();
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Really amazing.

One question. How should I handle the method if the number of `examples` (collected through `getAllExamples();`) is numerous? I confirmed that this works when it processes 100 or 1,000 examples, but an error happens when it processes 10,000+ examples, returning `Function invocation was interrupted. Error: memory limit exceeded.`
Is it a good idea to add another method to limit the number of `examples` to be processed at one time and repeat itself? Or, is there another efficient way to handle this huge object?

Comment: See the answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73440411/3371862